# Parse.com - WebApp with Facebook Login in Cloud Code

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am new with Cloud Code and Express , and there is no tutorial in Parse.com like Facebook Blank App (Android/iOS) to webapps using Cloud Code.

I read the guide and the exemple of game AnyYolk, but I still dont understand how to use Parse.FacebookUtils to get the data and save it.

Could anyone explain the cicle of the login users with cloud code or any source code example?

Thanks!